# Como colocar uma foto ao lado de um texto?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho uns 10 "< p" no meu documento, eu quero colocar uma foto ao lado de um texto. Um exemplo perfeito do que eu quero fazer está logo a baixo na foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: veja esse link aqui:
http://tableless.github.io/iniciantes/manual/css/float-clear.html

Comment: Possível duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170103/3635, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62652/3635 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30057/3635

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho Muito obrigado.